# Getting NA for join values - left_join() in dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm new to the dplyr package and trying on a `join` operation for two data frames.

The data is as follows

```
> overview
Source: local data frame [972 x 14]

       household                        names  x2003  x2004  x2005  x2006  x2007  x2008  x2009  x2012 last.avail last.avail.year absChange.last annChange.last
           (chr)                       (fctr)  (int)  (int)  (int)  (int)  (int)  (int)  (int)  (int)      (int)           (dbl)          (int)          (dbl)
1  single parent            totala utgifterna 215300 219870 241920 241060 229290 253590 255950 277260     277260            2012          61960     0.02850119
2  single parent              köpta livsmedel  26420  27910  28160  29100  28310  33020  35910  33740      33740            2012           7320     0.02754621
3  single parent     bröd, spannmålsprodukter   4760   5770   4940   5360   5070   5830   6310     NA       6310            2009           1550     0.04810245
4  single parent     ris och produkter av ris    240    290    210    230    220    280    420     NA        420            2009            180     0.09775732
5  single parent                          ris    100     70     70    130    110    180    200     NA        200            2009            100     0.12246205
6  single parent                 risprodukter    140    220    130    100    120    100    220     NA        220            2009             80     0.07824083
7  single parent pasta och produkter av pasta    410    450    370    460    580    490    600     NA        600            2009            190     0.06551908

> translation
Source: local data frame [8 x 2]

            translation                                   household
                 (fctr)                                      (fctr)
1          Accomodation                                      bostad
2   Leisure and culture                           fritid och kultur
3        Transportation                                   transport
4      Bought Groceries                             köpta livsmedel
5 Rent for accomodation hyra/avgift för hyres-/borätt (inkl garage)
6    Household services                            hushållstjänster
7           Rents (net)                             räntor (brutto)
8          Car expenses                                drift av bil
```

Now when I run `left_join(overview, translation)` I get the following result.

```
> left_join(overview, translation)
Joining by: "household"
Source: local data frame [972 x 15]

       household                        names  x2003  x2004  x2005  x2006  x2007  x2008  x2009  x2012 last.avail last.avail.year absChange.last annChange.last translation
           (chr)                       (fctr)  (int)  (int)  (int)  (int)  (int)  (int)  (int)  (int)      (int)           (dbl)          (int)          (dbl)      (fctr)
1  single parent            totala utgifterna 215300 219870 241920 241060 229290 253590 255950 277260     277260            2012          61960     0.02850119          NA
2  single parent              köpta livsmedel  26420  27910  28160  29100  28310  33020  35910  33740      33740            2012           7320     0.02754621          NA
3  single parent     bröd, spannmålsprodukter   4760   5770   4940   5360   5070   5830   6310     NA       6310            2009           1550     0.04810245          NA
4  single parent     ris och produkter av ris    240    290    210    230    220    280    420     NA        420            2009            180     0.09775732          NA
5  single parent                          ris    100     70     70    130    110    180    200     NA        200            2009            100     0.12246205          NA
6  single parent                 risprodukter    140    220    130    100    120    100    220     NA        220            2009             80     0.07824083          NA
```

As you can see, all the translations are of NA values. On for example index number `[2, 'names']` translation should equal "Bought groceries" but it doesn't.

What has happened and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `household` column in `translation` should actually be called `names` so that it will have the same name as the corresponding column in `overview`. Your current code is joining by the `household` column in each data frame, but these have no corresponding values, so you don't get any matches between the two data frames.

You could make your code work in its current form by specifying the join columns explicitly:

```
left_join(overview, translation, by=c("names"="household"))
```

In this case, it would be better to fix the column names to avoid confusion between the two data frames. Nevertheless, I like to specify the join columns explicitly so that I can see exactly what the code is doing.

Comment: I tried the by.x and by.y method, but it gave me an error. It seems this has been replaced with by = c("names" = "household") syntax?

Comment: See updated code. I forgot to add quotation marks around the column names.

Comment: It is strange. When I use your syntax i get error message: Error: No common variables. Please specify `by` param. But when using the syntax in the help page it works....

Comment: Ah, right. I was using the syntax from the `merge` function. `left_join` is different. I've fixed that now too. Sorry about that.